# PHP Convert string into array

Tags: php, arrays, string, converters

How to convert a string `$string = 'array(array("a"=>"content"))';`   (<-- this is string)
into array like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["a"]=> string(7) "content" } }
```

I am going to build a function to run serialize online:

Input: `$string = 'array(array(1))'; echo serialize($string);`

Result: `a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;i:1;}}` **NOT**  `s:16:"array(array(1)))";`

You call: `$returnValue = serialize('array(array(1))');`

Comment: My question would be why you have such a string in the first place?

Comment: Please provide more context. You had two people answer eval when you already knew that eval is insecure and not a solution. Don't waste people's time suggesting things that you rule out right from the start. Note the section "Be specific" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: @Gordon: I updated more info above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You /could/ use [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval):

```
$string = 'array(array("a"=>"content"))';
eval("\$array = $string;");
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => content
        )

)
```

But if you're accepting user inputs, you **should not** use `eval()`.

Also, consider using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) / [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) instead.

Alternatively, to store arrays in strings, you could use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Comment: if $string get data from $_POST like: $string = $_POST['string']; 
Like this:
$string = 'array(array("a"=>"content")); die("HACK: add more functions before this")';
eval("\$array = $string;");
print_r($array);

Comment: I still hack if using eval()
`$string = 'array(array("a"=>"content")); die("HACK: add more functions before this")';
eval("\$array = $string;");
print_r($array);`
**Output:**

`HACK: add more functions before this`

Comment: @Truongnq If you are gettig the string from outside you should write a parser.  It might be better to agree on something simpler, like JSON.

Comment: @Truongnq: As I mentioned in the answer, you shouldn't use eval if it involves accepting input from user. Would've been kind of nice if you'd mentioned in your question that you don't want to use eval. Anyway I've suggested alternatives - you might want to check it out. :-)

Comment: @AmalMurali: I can see your updated answer. Can you explain more.
Thanks!

Comment: @AmalMurali: I updated information in the question. Please give me your hands.

Answer (score 0):

eval? check http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

take note on the Caution the manual shows...

Comment: eval is not security when I public this kind of function only.
I tried, and hacked it when use eval.

Comment: I tried:

    $reg_exp = "/array\(*.*\)/";
    $subject ="array(array(1=>'123'))";
    $result = preg_split($reg_exp,$subject);
    var_dump($result);

**Output:**

    array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }

but this is NOT correct.

Please help!