# Extract data from string and set as new string

Tags: php

I am retrieving information from a string, lets call it $data and the output is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Doe
)
```

How can take the portion of the Full name and set that as a new string, say $fullname

the value of $fullname should be: `John Doe`

Comment: it ain't a string, it already says on the dump `Array`, just assign it into another variable, `$fullname = $data[0];`

Comment: If you really mean your string looks like `$data = "Array([0] => 'John Doe')"`, then a look at [the following question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162754/php-convert-string-into-array) will probably be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `$fullname = $data[0]`.

Since `$data` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass that value within a variable and can easily access it

Lets Say

```
$data = array('Jon Doe'); // output Array([0] => Jon Doe)

$fullname = $data[0]; // initialized value within $fullname

echo $fullname; // output Jon Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `string`. It is an `array`. And you can access array element by its `index`es. like -

```
$data = array(0 => "John Doe");
echo $data[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the value even without using "=>". Even if that is not used, the system takes "John Doe" as 0th value of that array only. It simply can be,

```
$data = array("John Doe");
echo $data[0];
```